# Pagination with UITableview?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, pagination

I'm a newbie in iOS developer. There is 100 records in my webservice. I read them from webservice and bind them into the UITableview. My problem is, I just want to bind only 20 record into my tableView and other 80 are for the pagination with UITableView. Who can tell me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried anything yet ?

Comment: i follow any answer in this site but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **UITableViewDataSource** methods:

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section //return 20 or how rows remains for last page
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath //set the cell and the data for each cell in a page